# Can Cassandra statements inside a batch have separate timestamps using cpp driver?

Tags: cassandra

If I use a Cassandra batch statement using CQL, then each statement can have an individual timestamp.  For example, something like:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO users (name, surname) VALUES ('Bob', 'Smith') USING TIMESTAMP 10000001;
  DELETE FROM users USING TIMESTAMP 10000000 WHERE user='Bob';
APPLY BATCH;
```

If I try to do something similar using the C++ driver, I'd do something like this:

1. Create the batch with cass_batch_new
2. Create the statements with cass_future_get_prepared then cass_prepared_bind
3. Set the timestamp on each statement with cass_statement_set_timestamp
4. Add the statement to the batch using cass_batch_add_statement
5. Execute the batch using cass_session_execute_batch

I'd then expect this to behave in the same way as the CQL batch statement, in as much as each statement in the batch is executed with its own separate timestamp.  But, based on my testing, I've not been able to get this to work. It appears to executed the entire batch using a single timestamp.

Similarly, if I create a monotonic timestamp generator to generate the timestamps for me, it appears to just use a timestamp for the batch and not for the individual statements.

I've taken a look at the source code for the C++ driver and it looks like when it encodes the statements in the batch for sending to the database (in ExecuteRequest::encode_batch), it doesn't attempt to encode a timestamp for each statement in the batch, just for the batch overall. When encoding individual statements not in a batch it does encode the timestamp for the statement (in ExecuteRequest::internal_encode).

As a workaround, instead of setting the timestamp on the statements using cass_statement_set_timestamp, I can put the "USING TIMESTAMP 10000001" directly into the CQL string, and that then works as intended. So, it appears that the database can correctly have separate timestamps on each statement in the batch, but the C++ driver can't send them.

But putting the timestamp directly into the CQL with "USING TIMESTAMP 10000001" then I can't reuse the statement by just binding new values to it. I'd need to prepare the statement again.

Has anyone else tried this and managed to get it to work?  Or is it just a known limitation of the C++ driver?

I'm using Cassandra C++ driver version 2.2.2 and database version 2.2.5 which as far as I can tell is using native protocol version 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also raised this on the Cassandra C++ driver mailing list Google group and Michael Penick replied to say it's not currently possible. The underlying protocol does not support a timestamp per statement in the batch, so the driver is not able to send one.

[Native Protocol v4 spec](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/doc/native_protocol_v4.spec#L379-L439)